# Выдает ошибку при попытке переопределить toString()

Tags: java, классы

Не могу понять почему выдает ошибку при попытке переопределить `toString()`. Цель переопределить в родительском и наследуемом классе.

```
package cs520.hw2.part2;

public class OnlineCourse extends Course{
    
    private int technologyFee;

    public OnlineCourse(String name, int cost, int number, int fee) 
    {
        super(name, cost, number);
        technologyFee = fee;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
    return (super.toString() + 
            "\n TechnologyFee = $" + getTechnologyFee());
    }       
    
    public void setTechnologyFee(int fee)
    {
        technologyFee = fee;
    }
    public int getTechnologyFee()
    {
        return technologyFee;
    }
    
    int totaltechnologyFee;
    public int getTotalTuition()
    {
        totaltechnologyFee = getTotalTuition() + technologyFee;
        
        return totaltechnologyFee;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
    return ("Course: " + getName() +
            " @ $" + getTotalTuition());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ...какую ошибку?

Comment: В показанном коде метод `toString` определён дважды в одном классе, или это должно означать реализации в разных классах?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка о переполнении стэка. Потому что из метода `toString` вызывается метод `getTotalTuition`, а тот, в свою очередь обращается сам к себе. В итоге он рекурсивно вызывает себя бесконечно и стэк переполняется.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем также примере есть несколько ошибочных вещей:

```
int totaltechnologyFee;
public int getTotalTuition()
{
    totaltechnologyFee = getTotalTuition() + technologyFee;
    
    return totaltechnologyFee;
}
```

1. Вы вызываете метод getTotalTuition() из самого себя - это бесконечная рекурсия. Возможно Вы хотите обратиться к родительскому методу `getTotalTuition()`, тогда следует вызывать это как `super.getTotalTuition()`.
2. Используйте аннотации `@Override`. Это сделать переопределение более наглядным, а Ваш код более качественным.
3. У вас не может быть два метода с одинаковой сигнатурой в одном классе. В данном случае речь идет про метод `toString()`
4. Если Вы используете локальную переменную, то создавайте ее локально. Не нужно создавать переменную `totaltechnologyFee` вне метода, если она не будет вызвана нигде кроме этого самого метода.